# TypeError: this.productService.getHomeData is not a function at HomeComponent.ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting this error while while doing npm run serve:ssr

my app.module.ts looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [ProductService,
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My home.component.ts looks like this:

```
constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getHomeData().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  
  }
```

my product.service looks like this:

```
@Injectable()

export class ProductService {
  getHomeData(): Observable<any> {
    return "this.data";
  }
}
```

Kindly help me fix this issue

```
ERROR TypeError: this.productService.getHomeData is not a function
    at HomeComponent.ngOnInit
```

Comment: maby u return string, but need of(...)

Comment: You are missing the `query` parameter in the method.

Comment: mistakenly put query there, I have removed it in the question. however, this issue does not occur of this. I am still getting the issue after following below answer.

Comment: update your question when

Comment: first change your returned type to "( ) : string" instead of "( ): Observable<any>" , second in the @Injectable(..) decorator, put this object between parentheses like this :
@injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
})